# h2o in R : model produces a negative predClass value when my target feature is binary. What does this mean?

Tags: r, h2o

My model is producing a negative prediction classifier when my target feature is binary. Does this mean the neural net in h2o.deeplearning just thinks negative values are over 100% likely to be a zero?

my code is as follows:

```
modeldataset <- h2o.importFile(path = modeldata)

train<- as.h2o(modeldataset)
model<- h2o.deeplearning(x = colnames(train[1:45]), y = "Target", training_frame=train, 'exact_quantiles= False', score_training_samples = 0)

as.h2o(testdata)
as.h2o(modeldataset)

testdata$predClass = h2o.predict(model, newdata=testdata)    # obtain the class (0/1)
testdata$predProb = h2o.predict(model, newdata=testdata)

 h2o.exportFile(testdata, 'file/path', parts = 1)
```

Why would some of my predictions be negative? apologies in advance for any formatting errors, I am a new user of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please post a fully reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been asked a few times, and generally the issue is that you forgot to either convert your numeric valued response as a factor (see the [as.factor](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-r/docs/reference/as.factor.html) function) and/or specifying the `distribution` parameter in the algorithm as `bernoulli`.

Take a look at the [documentations](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/distribution.html) overview of the distribution parameter it should help clear things up.